How do I store a record property as a uint but render it as a DateTime?
Minimal example dotnet fiddle available here.
I have to wrap a 3rd-party API that stores dates as uint seconds post-epoch, but want to present them to consumers of my API as DateTime values. The mechanics of get/init the DTO record property is tripping me up. If I do as below, then I get a "can't implicitly convert from uint to DateTime" error:
public static void Main()
{
    var foobar = new FoobarModel() { created = (uint)1725747561 };
}


public static class TimeConverter
{
    public static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(uint timestamp) =>
        DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds((double)timestamp);

    public static uint? ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date) =>
        (uint)Math.Floor((date!.ToUniversalTime() - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds);
}

public record FoobarModel
{
    private uint? _created;
    public DateTime? created
    {
        get => created != null
            ? TimeConverter.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(_created!.Value)
            : null;
        init => _created = value != null
            ? TimeConverter.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(value!.Value)
            : null;
    }

    public FoobarModel() { }
}

I have to be able to instantiate a FoobarModel with uint data, but clearly my FoobarModel.created.init method isn't able to accept uint. How do I make this situation work?
(Please forgive the FoobarModel property capitalization conventions, they match the 3rd party API. Also, eventually I would like to deserialize a JSON string with this property, so the fiddle has a little JSON code available.)

There's at least two solutions: 1) Don't use the same model in your API response as the one you get from the other API. 2) If you're serialising to JSON, use a JsonConverter to output that as an ISO8601 date/time in the JSON. Though this option might cause issues if you're also deserializing from JSON from the other API.

@ProgrammingLlama Thanks for the suggestions. 1) Was hoping to avoid duplicating as I have about 15 DTOs to duplicate, and would be not very DRY to maintain. 2) Swagger handles the serialization, and I didn't want to have to customize it much; would far prefer to keep the logic in the public init if possible. Is there truly no way to get around the type error?

Consider keeping the formatted DateTime as a separate non-serialized value if you want to dual-purpose the model:
public static class TimeConverter
{
    public static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(uint timestamp) =>
        DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds((double)timestamp);
    public static DateTime? ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(uint? timestamp) =>
        timestamp == null ? (DateTime?) null : ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(timestamp!);

    public static uint ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date) =>
        (uint)Math.Floor((date.ToUniversalTime() - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds);
}

public uint? created { get; init; }
[JsonIgnore]
public DateTime? createdDateTime
{
    get => TimeConverter.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(created)
}

I also just moved the #nullable handling into the converter.
The serialization/deserialization as well as any initialization continues to use the uint epoch values. Where you want to display it as a date-time use the createdDateTime property.

Yep, I had just come around to realizing that I needed another public property with just a getter as returning a DateTime on a uint property isn't type-safe. Thanks for the answer.
